# VB.net: How to define a namespace where the first segment is NOT the file name?

Tags: vb.net

Suppose I have a project called `FooProject` with a file called `FooModel.vb` which contains the following interfaces:

```
Namespace Foo.Model 

    Public Interface Foo
    ' ...
    End Interface

    Public Interface Bar
    ' ...
    End Interface
End Namespace
```

When I output this to a class library and import the DLL, the namespace I have to use is `FooProject.Foo.Model`. How do I tell VB.net to call it `Foo.Model` other from renaming the project to `Foo` and defining the namespace as `Model`?

Comment: Project + Properties, Application tab, Root namespace setting.  By default it is the same name as the project name.  You'd have to set it to an empty string to get what you want.  Do be careful, it is fine with the snippet you posted but VB.NET does make it very easy to get other Module declarations in the global namespace.  You won't like the My namespace to be global for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the Root namespace from the project properties:

[image: Image of the project properties screen with the root namespace highlighted]

Answer (score 1):

When you use `NameSpace` declarations in code, VB appends them to the Root Name Space defined for the project (its not the filename).  In this case, it would appear to be `FooProject`.

If you want to manage Namespaces a bit more the way C# does, go to **Project -> Properties -> Application** and remove the "Root Namespace" - this is the bit that gets prepended to each Namespace you might add.